# Satisfying inequality of large powers

Tags: inequality

You are not **ALLOWED** to use calculator to solve this question.

Here is the question:

Find the **largest natural number** "n" which satisfies the inequality $n^{6033}<2011^{2011}$

It would be easy if they ask you to solve without being a natural number.Here are my working steps if I were to solve $n^{6033}=2011^{2011}$

$n^{2011^3}=2011^{2011}$

$\sqrt [3] {2011}^{6033}=2011^{2011}$

$n=\sqrt [3] {2011}$

So with this result,I have to find $n<\sqrt [3] {2011}$ where n is a largest natural number.

The problem is,I cannot evaluate $\sqrt [3] {2011}$ because there is no working other than the special long division working which I could not understand.

So how do I evaluate $\sqrt [3] {2011}$?If not,is there another way to solve this?

Please do not use Guess and Check/Trial and Error to solve the answer.It is tedious and a bit non-mathematical way to solve.

Comment: You should write "$(n^{2011})^3$" instead of "$n^{2011^3}$" because they are completely different.

Comment: Can you explain why it is different?

Comment: @user21820 got it,I just want to know why it is different.Thanks for clarification

Comment: "$a^{b^c}$" always means "$a^{(b^c)}$" by mathematical convention.

Comment: @user21820 ahh,make sense thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's one of the many conventions we all have to get used to. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you need to solve for $n$ $$f(n)=n^3-2011=0$$ You can see that $f(10)<0$. You can use Newton method starting at $n_0=10$. Since $f'(n)=3n^2$, the iterative scheme is simple and one iteration gives $n_1=13.37$. Then, do it again by hand with $n_0=13$; now $n_1=12.63$.

When it will be time, you will learn that there methods faster than Newton; they are named Halley, Householder ...Using them starting at $n_0=10$, and so only using powers and multiples of $10$, they will give you as answer for $n_1$ $\frac{1337}{100}$, $\frac{1223431}{100000}$, $\frac{772331353}{60000000}$

Comment: Thanks for giving me an excellent answer here.Haha I'm just a 13 years old Solving this so I can't really understand.Don't worry.I will research on this slowly.I'm autistically born for math so I will learn fast

Comment: I suspected that you could be young but what I wanted was to show you is what you will be learning within very very few years. If you are interested by solving equations, look at Newton method in Wikipedia or let us discuss. It will be my pleasure to explain the very simple idea. Cheers :-)

Comment: cheers to you too!Okay,I will search about that guy who discovered gravity by having an apple dropping to his head

Comment: I am 73 and it is the first time in my whole life I hear somebody speaking about Sir Isaac Newton as *" that guy who discovered gravity by having an apple dropping to his head"* but I like it ! With your permission, I shall reuse it !

Comment: Aww thanks!I knew Issac Newton by my teacher sharing this when I was 9,when my teacher is going through Gravitational Force.She told us this story :P

Comment: Which is a perfectly true and nice story to tell and to explain Gravitational Force. My best wishes for your studies. Please, when they will teach you Newton method in math, remember an old Frenchman you made happy ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $12^3<2011<13^3$.

Comment: Yes,but how do you get $12^3$ ? Guess and check?

Comment: It's helpful to memorize your simple squares and cubes up to about 13. You technically wouldn't have used a calculator!

Comment: Okay!I only remembered up to $15^2=255$ and $5^3=125$ :P.Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @pyrazolam "up to about 13" how convenient... :D

Comment: @Thomas I don't get the joke here

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to simplify the problem:

Assume that $n^{6033} < 2011^{2011}$. Then,

$(n^3)^{2011} < (2011)^{2011}$. Using the one-to-one property, you can say that $n^3 < 2011$. Then, observe that $12^3 = 1728$ and $13^3 = 2197$.

Thus, the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^3 < 2011$ or equivalently, $n^{6033} < 2011^{2011}$ is $n = 12$.

Comment: I can observe this,and that was the answer,I forgotten to state that I would not like to use guess and check to solve the answer because of its tediousness